# How do I decode URL in Android Application?

Tags: java, android, url

I am trying to write an Android app, and it's supposed to retrieve the content of a CDN URL, which are always URLEncoded. For the sake of example, I am using a youtube URL, because they are formatted the same way.

```
    public static String getText(String url) throws Exception {
    URL website = new URL(url);
    URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                                connection.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        response.append(inputLine);

    in.close();

    return response.toString();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    String page = getText("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH2-TGUlwu4");
    String[] temper = page.split("flashvars=\"");
    page = temper[1];
    temper = page.split("\"     allowscriptaccess=\"always\"");
    page = temper[0];
    temper = page.split("url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=");
    page = temper[1];
    temper = page.split("fallback_host");
    page = temper[0];
    page = page.replaceAll("url%3D", ""); **
    page = URLDecoder.decode(page, "UTF-8"); **
    page = page.replaceAll("hd720&", "hd720"); **
    System.out.println(page);
    
        // TODO code application logic here
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(app.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The code that is starred is (probably) where it is giving me trouble. The system.out.println outputs

```
http%3A%2F%2Fo-o.preferred.ord08s01.v3.lscache1.c.youtube.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fsparams%3Did%252Cexpire%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Csource%252Cratebypass%252Ccp%26fexp%3D909708%252C907322%252C908613%26itag%3D44%26ip%3D99.0.0.0%26signature%3D2889261E861AF0E724519652960C1BF31DA5BABD.A621580215B6416151470893E2D07BDE7AFF081E%26sver%3D3%26ratebypass%3Dyes%26source%3Dyoutube%26expire%3D1327316557%26key%3Dyt1%26ipbits%3D8%26cp%3DU0hRTFNMVF9KUUNOMV9LRlhGOlNaUzBvTG1tdEp2%26id%3D407dbe4c6525c2ee&quality=large&
```

I want that URL decoded in a way that I can wrap it in a method to download it.

I have already tried the string.replaceAll() method. In short, It doesn't work

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: The Android version of [URLDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLDecoder.html).

Answer (score 117):

The string you have there is URL encoded.

```
String afterDecode = URLDecoder.decode(stringvalue, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: `Uri.decode(String)`  (android.net.Uri)

Comment: @hmac, your answer is more android related and should be the correct one. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

using [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html)