# Is there a way to use json format emoticon on android?

Tags: android, emoji, emoticons

I want to receive emoticon from emoji-datasource site as json file and show it in android. How do you do it? The file in json format is:

```
[
    {
        "name": "HASH KEY",
        "unified": "0023-FE0F-20E3",
        "non_qualified": "0023-20E3",
        "docomo": "E6E0",
        "au": "EB84",
        "softbank": "E210",
        "google": "FE82C",
        "image": "0023-fe0f-20e3.png",
        "sheet_x": 0,
        "sheet_y": 0,
        "short_name": "hash",
        "short_names": [
            "hash"
        ],
        "text": null,
        "texts": null,
        "category": "Symbols",
        "sort_order": 132,
        "added_in": "0.0",
        "has_img_apple": true,
        "has_img_google": true,
        "has_img_twitter": true,
        "has_img_facebook": false
    },
    {
        "name": null,
        "unified": "002A-FE0F-20E3",
        "non_qualified": "002A-20E3",
        "docomo": null,
        "au": null,
        "softbank": null,
        "google": null,
        "image": "002a-fe0f-20e3.png",
        "sheet_x": 0,
        "sheet_y": 1,
        "short_name": "keycap_star",
        "short_names": [
            "keycap_star"
        ],
        "text": null,
        "texts": null,
        "category": "Symbols",
        "sort_order": 133,
        "added_in": "0.0",
        "has_img_apple": true,
        "has_img_google": true,
        "has_img_twitter": true,
        "has_img_facebook": false
    },
    ...
]
```

Link is here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-datasource.
I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
textView.text = String(Character.toChars(0x002AFE0F20E3))
```

I want to show the user all the emoticons available on the Android device.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I solved it. Just use in json file `google` name code.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know that this would serve as a solution but I did something different and wanna share it here so everyone knows.

Content that I create from Android app gets encoded using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967253/how-do-i-decode-url-in-android-application). When fetching from server, I decode this using the same method. Content includes emojis as well and they appear perfectly in all devices without knowing the names of the emojis.